# How to allow Spring Security 6 to permit general ressources (static, images, etc...)

Tags: spring-security-6

I'm on Spring Security 6, and having a trouble when rending pages:
as I'm using Thymeleaf, the static repertory isn't allowed.

This is my filter

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/auth/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
         
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
```

When try to add

```
@Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static");
    }
```

it seem as depreciated.

But When I edit the filter like this

```
.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/**")
                        .permitAll()
```

Everything is correct.

May someone know by what it has been replaced ..??

thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to give static resources access, Hope below steps can help 

- Keep all your css/js/images under static => dist folder 

- update securityFilterChain method with below code 

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/auth/**", "/dist/**")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated());

        return httpSecurity.build();
    } 



- try load css/js/images like below Thymeleaf code

 <link rel="stylesheet"   th:href="@{/dist/css/style.css}" />

 <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/dist/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js}"></script>

 <img th:src="@{/dist/images/your_image.png}" alt="" />
```